# Исключить определенные значения из массива с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть массив

```
const all = ['dog.png', 'cat.jpg', 'pigeon.jpg', 'sparrow.webp', 'car.txt']
```

Для получения просто всех картинок я использую

```
const  allImages = all.filter(RegExp.prototype.test, /(png|jpg|webp)/);
```

Но мне необходимо получить все картинки за исключением pigeon.jpg. Подскажите как мне это сделать? Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

например, так

```
^(?!pigeon\.jpg$).+\.(png|jpg|webp)$
```

Negative Lookahead `(?!pigeon\.jpg$)` проверит, что строка не содержит pigeon.jpg. И лучше убедиться, что расширения в конце строки, иначе jpegs.txt тоже пройдет тест

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/5OSwN0/3)

Answer (score 2):

Есть "Negative lookbehind" — `(?<!что-то, что не должно быть перед)(основным выражением)`

И точку `\.` не забыть...

```js
const all = ['dog.png', 'cat.jpg', 'pigeon.jpg', 'sparrow.webp', 'car.txt'];

const allImages = all.filter( e => (/(?<!pigeon)\.(png|jpg|webp)/i).test(e) );

console.log( allImages );
```

Но сейчас совсем мало браузеров его поддерживают → https://caniuse.com/#search=lookbehind

Comment: `/(?<!pigeon)\.(png|jpg|webp)/i` — неверное решение, т.к. отфильтрует и  `pigeon.webp` и `pigeon.png`